# Add textview with button in gallery

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I'm working on a project that contains some images in gallery, I want to add text with button that changes respective to selected image. How can I add this?

This is the code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

 public class GalleryView extends Activity {
Integer[] pics = {
        R.drawable.antartica1,
        R.drawable.antartica2,
        R.drawable.antartica3,
        R.drawable.antartica4,
        R.drawable.antartica5,
        R.drawable.antartica6,
        R.drawable.antartica7,
        R.drawable.antartica8,
        R.drawable.antartica9,
        R.drawable.antartica10
};
ImageView imageView;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Gallery ga = (Gallery)findViewById(R.id.Gallery01);
    ga.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
    ga.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                    "You have selected picture " + (arg2+1) + " of Antartica", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            imageView.setImageResource(pics[arg2]);

        }

    });

}


public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context ctx;
    int imageBackground;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        ctx = c;
        TypedArray ta = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery1);
        imageBackground = ta.getResourceId(R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground, 1);
        ta.recycle();
    }

    public int getCount() {

        return pics.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int arg0) {

        return arg0;
    }

    public long getItemId(int arg0) {

        return arg0;
    }

    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(ctx);
        iv.setImageResource(pics[arg0]);
        iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        iv.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150,120));
        iv.setBackgroundResource(imageBackground);
        return iv;
    }

}
}
```

Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<Gallery 
android:id="@+id/Gallery01" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Gallery>
<ImageView 
android:id="@+id/ImageView01" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>


 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well you can make your own Customised gallery in which every image can be viewed in a grid view followed by a text view below the thumbnail and a button (may be needed for deleting the image).

To view the images dynamically from the memory card you have to implement ArrayList or you can take other oferings of collection framework ..

i did the same and it worked with mine , hopefully will work with you too.